# Ajax call always return error function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have php page, page display in an iframe, that page contain one ajax call
 the code shows below

```
      $.ajax({
            url: "mindex.php",
            data: {
                model: "test",
                handler: "test_123",
                data: info
            },
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                if( response.success ){
                    createChart( response.times );
                }else{
                    $('#chart-container').html( '<p style="margin: 20px 100px; color: rgb(204, 71, 71);">'+response.errors+'</p>' );
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Unknown error Occured");
            }
        });
```

after run this page, always display 'Unknown error Occured';
Firebug shows no response (blank).

This page work in my localhost, but online shows error
Pls help me

thax in advance

Comment: make sure the url is correct at your production environment

Comment: The problem is whatever is in `mindex.php`, not the ajax. Check your PHP error log, it may be producing a fatal error which would explain the blank response. Also check the return code of the response, a fatal error will return a `500 inertnal server error`.

Comment: the url is correct, response not display in firebug, shows blank,

Comment: no errors found in error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing is wrong with `ajax` call.

from `mindex.php` you must need to return output in `json` format.

use `echo json_encode($response);` in `mindex.php` file.

Comment: Is there any problem using iframe, the page loaded in an iframe